# Matching Mailgun Webhook response event to Mailinglist E-mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks, mailgun

So I am using Mailgun API to send E-mails and recently started using their mailing list feature as well.

When I send to the mailing list for instance: somelist@mg.address.com

It returns a single message Id.

However when I receive the webhook responses that messageId is not contained within the data, it gives the message ID pertaining to the individual address mail sent by server. (So if i send an e-mail to somelist@somedomain.com which contains 100 addresses, I will receive notifications with 100 different message ID's.

I could potentially match it up by subject, but that doesn't seem right.. What is the correct way to match the event to the mailing list email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by generating a random tag when sending the email and including it in the data.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

Every MailGun Event that you will receive will have message ID in it. Usually it may be found under ***message.headers.message-id***. For instance, your event may look like this

```
{
    "id": "ABC123...",
    "message": {
        "headers": {
            "to": "somebody@somewhere.com",
            "message-id": "20211012201139.1.XYZ...@somedomain.com",
            "from": "you@somedomain.com",
            "subject": "Test email"
        },
        "attachments": [],
        "size": 29123
    },
    "event": "accepted"
    ...
}
```